# Where is the Controller initiated in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, controller

I would like to know where is the controller started (I mean where is the file included and then it's class is loaded and it's methods are called). I would like to know because I would like to create a minor modification to the core.

What I actually need is to simulate calling new controllers. I don't need a technology like HMVC but instead I am working on something much simpler but I really need to simulate calling controllers which could later interact with the requested controller.

I already extended the core's Loader class to enable calling new controllers through the loader class but I can't find where are the controllers initiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `system/core/CodeIgniter.php` from line 317 to 360 (CodeIgniter 2.1.0).

```
/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Call the requested method
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // Is there a "remap" function? If so, we call it instead
    if (method_exists($CI, '_remap'))
    {
        $CI->_remap($method, array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2));
    }
    else
    {
        // is_callable() returns TRUE on some versions of PHP 5 for private and protected
        // methods, so we'll use this workaround for consistent behavior
        if ( ! in_array(strtolower($method), array_map('strtolower', get_class_methods($CI))))
        {
            // Check and see if we are using a 404 override and use it.
            if ( ! empty($RTR->routes['404_override']))
            {
                $x = explode('/', $RTR->routes['404_override']);
                $class = $x[0];
                $method = (isset($x[1]) ? $x[1] : 'index');
                if ( ! class_exists($class))
                {
                    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php'))
                    {
                        show_404("{$class}/{$method}");
                    }

                    include_once(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php');
                    unset($CI);
                    $CI = new $class();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                show_404("{$class}/{$method}");
            }
        }

        // Call the requested method.
        // Any URI segments present (besides the class/function) will be passed to the method for convenience
        call_user_func_array(array(&$CI, $method), array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2));
    }
```

It still doesn't make any sense what you're trying to do, though.